# Converting Wide Format Data into Long Format with Multiple Indices and Grouped Data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, formatting

I have a data frame in wide format:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1, 2, 3], 
                   'factor': ['a','a','b'],
                   'variable1': [0,0,0],
                   'variable2': [0,0,1],
                   'variable3': [0,2,0],
                   'variable4': [2,0,1],
                   'variable5': [1,0,1],
                   'variable6': [0,1,1],                   
                   'O1V1': [0,0.2,-0.3],
                   'O1V2': [0,0.4,-0.9],
                   'O1V3': [0.5,0.2,-0.6],
                   'O1V4': [0.5,0.2,-0.6],
                   'O1V5': [0,0.2,-0.3],
                   'O1V6': [0,0.4,-0.9],
                   'O1V7': [0.5,0.2,-0.6],
                   'O1V8': [0.5,0.2,-0.6],                   
                   'O2V1': [0,0.5,0.3],
                   'O2V2': [0,0.2,0.9],
                   'O2V3': [0.6,0.1,-0.3],
                   'O2V4': [0.5,0.2,-0.6],
                   'O2V5': [0,0.5,0.3],
                   'O2V6': [0,0.2,0.9],
                   'O2V7': [0.6,0.1,-0.3],
                   'O2V8': [0.5,0.2,-0.6],                   
                   'O3V1': [0,0.7,0.4],
                   'O3V2': [0.9,0.2,-0.3],
                   'O3V3': [0.5,0.2,-0.7],
                   'O3V4': [0.5,0.2,-0.6],
                   'O3V5': [0,0.7,0.4],
                   'O3V6': [0.9,0.2,-0.3],
                   'O3V7': [0.5,0.2,-0.7],
                   'O3V8': [0.5,0.2,-0.6]})
```

Each row of the data frame represents a time period. There are multiple 'subjects' being monitored, namely O1, O2, and O3. Each subject has 8 variables being measured. I need to convert this data into long format where each row contains the information for one subject at a given time period, but with only the first 4 subject variables, as well as the extra information about this time period in columns 2-4, but not columns 5-8.

The final output should look as follows:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
                   'factor': ['a','a','b','a','a','b','a','a','b'],
                   'variable1': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'variable2': [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],                 
                   'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'V1': [0,0.2,-0.3,0,0.5,0.3,0,0.7,0.4],
                   'V2': [0,0.4,-0.9,0,0.2,0.9,0.9,0.2,-0.3],
                   'V3': [0.5,0.2,-0.6,0.6,0.1,-0.3,0.5,0.2,-0.7],
                   'V4': [0.5,0.2,-0.6,0.5,0.2,-0.6,0.5,0.2,-0.6]})
```

I can achieve this using a for loop as follows (this code sorts the data by time instead of id, but sorting by id is not a requirement):

```
import numpy as np

#make every 8 columns of first row into its own row
long = np.array(df.iloc[0,:]).reshape(-1,8)

#make array of numbers 1-3 (I'm not an experienced python programmer, 
#so I suspect that this is a very verbose way of achieving this)
array = np.arange(3)
array = array.reshape(3,1)
array+=1

#concatenate first 4 columns of first row with first four columns of every other row, adding index from array variable
long = np.concatenate([np.tile(long[0,:4].reshape(-1,4),(3,1)),array,long[1:,:4]],axis=1) 

#repeat this process for each object id and concatenate
for i in [1,2]:
    temp = np.array(df.iloc[i,:]).reshape(-1,8)    
    temp = np.concatenate([np.tile(temp[0,:4].reshape(-1,4),(3,1)),array,temp[1:,:4]],axis=1) 
    long = np.concatenate([long,temp])
```

This method achieves the desired result, however I have problems with it:

1. This method relies on the fact that there are 8 variables before the subject variables appear, allowing the .reshape (-1,8) line to work. I am trying to find a method which would work regardless of the number of non-subject variables.
2. The for loop in this solution seems avoidable. I have tried looking for ways to utilize NumPy functions to achieve this but have not found any, or at least do not understand how to use them like this. I understand I could write my own function and apply it to every row, however I am specifically looking to learn about using typical Python packages as I am new to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `wide_to_long`. Either drop the columns you don't need in the beginning, or reshape everything and then subset after: We need to reverse some of the column names since 'O3V6' should be in the form 'V6O3' for the stubs to work (and here we'll just make it 'V63' so the id doesn't have the O before it).

```
df = df.rename(columns={x: x[2:]+x[1:2] for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('O')]})

df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df, i=['time', 'factor']+[f'variable{i}' for i in range(1,7)], 
                      j='id', stubnames=[f'V{i}' for i in range(1,9)], suffix='.*')

df1 = (df1.reset_index()
          .drop(columns=[f'V{i}' for i in range(5,9)]
                        +[f'variable{i}' for i in range(3,7)]))
```

---

```
   time factor  variable1  variable2  id   V1   V2   V3   V4
0     1      a          0          0   1  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5
1     1      a          0          0   2  0.0  0.0  0.6  0.5
2     1      a          0          0   3  0.0  0.9  0.5  0.5
3     2      a          0          0   1  0.2  0.4  0.2  0.2
4     2      a          0          0   2  0.5  0.2  0.1  0.2
5     2      a          0          0   3  0.7  0.2  0.2  0.2
6     3      b          0          1   1 -0.3 -0.9 -0.6 -0.6
7     3      b          0          1   2  0.3  0.9 -0.3 -0.6
8     3      b          0          1   3  0.4 -0.3 -0.7 -0.6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like this answer but the output is not the same as the desired output. Is there a way to convert this such that time, factor, variable 1 and variable 2 are displayed in every row?

Comment: I achieved this using a line from David Erickson's answer: df1 = df1.reset_index().sort_values(['id','time'])

Answer (score 0):

Set first columns as the index :

```
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains("O\dV\d")]
df = df.set_index(cols.tolist())
```

Create multiindex from the remaining columns - we separate the numbers before V :

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(int(col[1:2]), col[2:]) 
                                         for col in df.columns
                                        ], 
                                         names = ['id', None]
                                       )
```

Now, we stack to get the id column, drop the columns and indexes we are not interested in to get the final output :

```
(df.stack(0)
 .iloc[:, :4]
 .sort_index(level="id")
 .droplevel([4, 5, 6, 7])
 .reset_index()
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the exact output:

1. Remove `O` + the number from the column names to get just `V` and the number
2. `.melt` the dataframe into a longer format
3. create an `id` column which will find the relevant group with `.groupby` and `.cumcount()+1`.
4. Set all of the non-values column to the index and use `.unstack(4)`to put the fifth column in the index as the header, which transforms the dataframe into a format that is close to what you are seeking.
5. Do some final cleaning/ formatting to get the data into the perfect format.

code:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('O[0-9]', '', regex=True)
cols = ['time', 'factor', 'variable1', 'variable2']
df = df.melt(id_vars=cols, value_vars=['V1','V2','V3','V4'])
df['id'] = df.groupby(cols + ['variable']).cumcount()+1
df = df.set_index(cols + ['id','variable']).unstack(5)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df = df.reset_index().sort_values(['id','time'])
df.columns.name = None
df
```

output:

```
    time factor variable1 variable2 id  V1   V2   V3    V4
0   1    a      0         0         1   0.0  0.0  0.5   0.5
3   2    a      0         0         1   0.2  0.4  0.2   0.2
6   3    b      0         1         1   -0.3 -0.9 -0.6  -0.6
1   1    a      0         0         2   0.0  0.0  0.6   0.5
4   2    a      0         0         2   0.5  0.2  0.1   0.2
7   3    b      0         1         2   0.3  0.9  -0.3  -0.6
2   1    a      0         0         3   0.0  0.9  0.5   0.5
5   2    a      0         0         3   0.7  0.2  0.2   0.2
8   3    b      0         1         3   0.4  -0.3 -0.7  -0.6
```